# I want to add separate animations to grouped elements in Microsoft Powerpoint. How do I do that?

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft

So, I have a bunch of shapes and once I group them I add the same background so that it looks like one picture is cut into different shapes. And I want to add different entry animations to make it look cool. But this isn't working. How do I add separate animations to grouped elements?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, when grouped, the animation is applied to all elements in the group. You can't animate individual elements.